# fb-request-form-submit in iFrame page tab problem

Tags: facebook

I created iFrame application for Sending invites to friends to join on my page. Every FB visitor can send invites to their friends. Selecting friends is working fine but after clicking button Send invite it opens fb-request-form-submit in a way it is just half seen (one part is missing). 
I believe it is connected with the fact that page tab has 520px width limit and fb-request-form-submit is more than 520 px so when within iFrame it doesn't pop-ups in a correct way.
How to resolve that?

On another FB page I have FBML tab with pure FBML code and there is working OK so it must be something with iFrame...

Answer (score 0):

About a month ago Facebook released a javascript based Request/invite dialog that doesn't use FBML. You may want to try using that instead. Using the standard "display" parameter for dialogs, you can specify you want it as a "popup" so it will appear in it's own window and won't have width restrictions.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Comment: thank you for your reply. Your link leads to a page where I have read this:"In the future, we will create an application specific setting for a developer to take the user directly to their canvas page instead of the games or application dashboard." That means that for the moment this type of request doesn't fit my need.

Comment: The notification will lead them to the dashboard, which will then have an "Accept" button to take them to the canvas page of your app. That's the way "invites" currently work.